# programmatic approach Google Indexed my link or not

Tags: java, php, indexing

How to problematically know that google bot has indexed our link. Is there any API provided by google in PHP or Java.
Please help me, I have to work a tool on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: analytics.google.com - Great tool for any developpers, website owners

Answer (score 3):

No. Google doesn't provide an API to check whether you have been indexed. You have a couple different options:

1. Monitor the access logs of your web server and watch for the Googlebot accessing your page.
2. Put some random content on the page that no other page returns results for and then search for it. If your page shows up, it's been indexed.

Answer (score 0):

google webmaster tools may help here